# CSV module failing to write

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have some code that I was working on, but it no longer works. I have ran the tests and everything passes. `writer.write(row)` runs. However when I go to my `sales_report/2017_sales_final.csv` the file is blank. It doesn't show the values from `in_file` and has a size of 0kb. What am I doing wrong?

```
fieldnames = ['Date', 'Order ID']
in_file = open('sales_report/hardcopy.csv', 'r')
out_file = open('sales_report/2017_sales_final.csv', "w")
reader = csv.DictReader(in_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
writer = csv.DictWriter(out_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

for row in reader:
    writer.writerow(row)

writer.writerow({'Your order': '12/15/2017','Order ID': '696969'})
```

Comment: The code here looks okay. Are you sure there's any data in the input file? Maybe the field names have changed?

Comment: You should always supply a `newline=''` keyword argument when opening csv files in Python 3. Try adding that.

Comment: Your last line looks very odd - the fieldnames are 'Date' and 'Order ID' but the last lines use different names. Where do order_date and order_id come from? You MUST post a MCVE (google it) to get useful help.

Comment: @martineau It does not work with the newline='' addition.

Comment: As @barny said, you need to post a MCVE. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also please include a few sample lines from input file, too.

Comment: Likely, you are looking at the file and it hasn't been closed yet.  Running the script via command line will probably show the file contents correctly because when Python exits the file handles will be closed, but if run in an IDE the handles may be left open.  Use a `with` statement to ensure your files are closed.

Answer (score 0):

Likely, you are looking at the file and it hasn't been closed yet.  Running the script via command line will probably show the file contents correctly because when Python exits the file handles will be closed, but if run in an IDE the handles may be left open.  Use a `with` statement to ensure your files are closed:

```
fieldnames = ['Date', 'Order ID']
with open('sales_report/hardcopy.csv', 'r') as in_file:
    with open('sales_report/2017_sales_final.csv', "w") as out_file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(in_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer = csv.DictWriter(out_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        # etc.

# files will be closed outside the with blocks.
```

Answer (score -1):

You never `close` the output file.